# How can we generate Reports using flex bulider?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex3, flexbuilder

is it possiable we can bulid the reports using flex bulider ?  or can we and any 
frameworks for build the reports ? . 
i don't know what way to bulid the reports

flex bulider have any build reports compoents there?

i want sorting reports order like

**By Product    Company Name    Expected Close Month
                                            Consultant  Expected Revenue**
this is are fields

> Product 1     A   May’10  X   £1,000.00
>     B   Jun’10  Y   £2,000.00           C   Jul’10
>     X   £3,000.00       Sub Total
>                 £6,000.00
>       Product 2 etc
>                         Grand Total             £24,000.00

This is are data . How is it possiable ?

Could u give any gudiends me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer based on first revision.*

Typically applications would give this responsibility to the server. Your Flex application passes parameters to the server with a request for a PDF document and the server puts together the appropriate one and seconds it back.

If you're using AIR to run your Flex application you could probably write a library to create a PDF file and then same it to the user's computer but I would stress that the kind of libraries you would need for your server already exist. For example: http://php.net/pdf

Comment: ok i can understand  and also very useful information but is it possiable witin flex? Means i want show reports to the user . In the foramt of chat and reports also , I did chat , it's working fine . How can i do reports ?

Comment: Ah, I had assumed you were looking for PDF reports -- that's typically what a "report" refers to in my understanding, otherwise you're just looking for display information from the server. This is very easy with Flex.

You'll still need a backend server which hosts a database with some scripted interface to it. Alternatively you're going to have to make your Flex application run in AIR which allows you to use SQLite which will allow you to store and query information to generate reports like that.

Answer (score 0):

Report tends to be a rather generic term and as the other responder indicated that it meant PDF to him/her.  The application I am working on is very report heavy.  We have a requirement for a client side report ("Think Report in Flex") and PDF version of the same report.

When we originally looked 1yr back,  there is no Report library that provides the equivalent of what lifecycle does on the server.    Therefore we have had to build our own and it is based on a generic template mechanism.

So can it be done.  Yes. But I would recommend developing a generic means to render your reports and it is not a easy task if you want to keep it generic so you can create multiple type of reports.

Also,  avoid the trap of nesting your reports through VBOX, HBOX and containers to provide a flexible layout system as it will not perform well.